# jedi-vim how to close __doc__ window and remove from buffer list?

Tags: vim, jedi-vim

I love being able to SHIFT-K and get the docstring on a class or function.  However, when I am done with the doc split at the top of my screen I have to navigate to it (CTRL-w) and close the split (:q).  And it is still in my buffer list, which is a bit annoying when I'm cycling through buffers.

I'm just wondering, am I missing a command or configuration  to close the split and remove it from the buffer list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `:bd` (you still need to put the cursor in that (sub-)window)?
A short explanation from vim's help file:

> Unload buffer [N] (default: current buffer) and delete it from the buffer list.

Comment: No, I do know how to manually change to that split and delete the buffer.  I'm just wondering if there was a command already mapped in jedi-vim that would do that for you.

Comment: Actually, after retrying your suggestion, that actually works pretty well.  When I SHIFT-K, I end up in the doc window, so :bd will close it and put me back in my original split.  I'll mark this as the correct answer.